# Why is my server very slow when I am running only one Odoo instance?

Tags: server, hardware, odoo, devops

My server is configured with a 32-core processor, but whenever I run an Odoo instance, it only utilizes one core while the remaining 31 cores remain idle. This causes the server to become overloaded.

What are some effective load-balancing techniques that can be used to distribute workload across multiple cores and alleviate server overload?

Comment: Try running Odoo with `--workers` > 0. See [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/deploy.html#worker-number-calculation) for recommended number of workers based on the number of available CPUs.

Comment: This is a problem for me too, post the solution if you find one@mani shankar

Comment: I have written the info pointed by @Naglis and I have added more clarifications in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Slowness reasons

First you need to check why Odoo is working slowly. There are several possible reasons. Some of them:

- **Odoo configuration is not set up correctly.**
- **Some specific task is slow because is badly programmed.** Check if some automatic task on the background is taking all the resources for instannce.
- **System resources are not enough.** Normally SSD is a good idea because the transactions are going to work 10x faster

### Odoo Configuration - Memory and Workers

You can set this attributes on the Odoo Configuration File:

Memory options:

```
--osv-memory-count-limit=OSV_MEMORY_COUNT_LIMIT
                    Force a limit on the maximum number of records kept in
                    the virtual osv_memory tables. The default is False,
                    which means no count-based limit.
--osv-memory-age-limit=OSV_MEMORY_AGE_LIMIT
                    Force a limit on the maximum age of records kept in
                    the virtual osv_memory tables. This is a decimal value
                    expressed in hours, and the default is 1 hour.
--max-cron-threads=MAX_CRON_THREADS
                    Maximum number of threads processing concurrently cron
                    jobs (default 2).
```

Multiprocessing options:

```
--workers=WORKERS   Specify the number of workers, 0 disable prefork mode.

--limit-memory-soft=LIMIT_MEMORY_SOFT
                    Maximum allowed virtual memory per worker, when
                    reached the worker be reset after the current request
                    (default 671088640 aka 640MB).
                    NOTA: if this size of memory is reached, a SIGINT signal is sent to Odoo to finish the process in a correct way

--limit-memory-hard=LIMIT_MEMORY_HARD
                    Maximum allowed virtual memory per worker, when
                    reached, any memory allocation will fail (default
                    805306368 aka 768MB).
                    NOTA: if this size of memory is reached, a SIGKILL signal is sent to Odoo to finish the process in a abrupt way

--limit-request=LIMIT_REQUEST
                    Maximum number of request to be processed per worker
                    (default 8192).
```

**Workers**. Non-zero values for `--workers` activates Multiprocessing. Multiprocessing increases stability, makes somewhat better use of computing resources and can be better monitored and resource-restricted.

**Number of Workers Calculation**:

- Rule of thumb : (#CPU * 2) + 1
- Cron workers need CPU
- 1 worker ~= 6 concurrent users

Although I read this on the Odoo forum or somewhere else:

> I use 2 worker threads + 1 cron thread per available CPU, and 1 CPU per 10 concurent users. Make sure you tune the memory limits and cpu limits.
>   I suggest close monitoring of the server resources (CPU, Memory, Network, etc.) in order to further tune the parameters.

**Memory Size Calculation**.

> We consider 20% of the requests are heavy requests, while 80% are simpler ones
>   A heavy worker, when all computed field are well designed, SQL requests are well designed, ... is estimated to consume around 1Go of RAM
>
> A lighter worker, in the same scenario, is estimated to consume around 150MB of RAM
>
> ```
> Needed RAM = #worker * ( (light_worker_ratio * light_worker_ram_estimation) + (heavy_worker_ratio * heavy_worker_ram_estimation) )
> ```

**PostgreSQL Memory**.

Set shared_buffers to 20% of the available memory, and effective_cache_size to 50% of the available memory. Change these parameters in the configuration file:

```
shared_buffers = 3072MB
effective_cache_size = 8192MB
```

It is recomended to [vacuum](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT) the database from time to time

### Example

If you have a VPS with 8 CPU cores and 16 GB of RAM, the number of workers should be 17 (CPU cores * 2 + 1), total limit-memory-soft value will be 640 x 17 = 10880 MB , and total limit-memory-hard 768MB x 17 = 13056 MB, so Odoo will use maximum 12.75 GB of RAM.

```
workers = 17
limit_memory_hard = 805306368    # total >> 13690208256
limit_memory_soft = 671088640    # total >> 11408506880
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 60
limit_time_real = 120
max_cron_threads = 2
```

### References

- [Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/deploy.html#worker-number-calculation)

Comment: You might wanna check your statement of the limit memory hard/soft, since it will allow each worker to go up all the way to the memory soft/hard before killing it. If 17 workers are allowed to go 12.75 GB, your machine will exhaust resources very likely. 

"Hard limit on virtual memory, any worker exceeding the limit will be immediately killed without waiting for the end of the current request processing." -> https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/cmdline.html

Comment: You are right @Ark74, I have made the division `total / 17`

Comment: Once that clarified, you might wanna stick to the default 2048MB (for Odoo 10) or higher, since otherwise you might have issues with process like style, which are memory consuming. Cheers!